# Extracting specific values from a table and exporting them to a new table

Tags: matlab

I have the following table:

[image]

Can Matlab extract rsquare values (Column 15) that are less than 0.95 and export the whole rows to a new table?

Comment: Do you want to select all the rows from the table such that for each row the value of `rsquare` variable is less than `0.95`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
rows = Table_old.rsquare<0.95; %//rows is a logical col vector containing 0 for values of rsquare > 0.95 and vice versa
Table_new = Table_old(rows,:); % // using a logical vector means that only those rows will be selected whose values in the logical vector are 1
```

Comment: FYI: This turned up in the low quality posts review queue due to a flagging. I suspect because it is a code only answer.

Comment: @OliverMatthews Please See the previous version of this answer , I hadearlier answered it completely wrong, That may be the reason for the flagging, but I am going to put some comments. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

Yes using logical addressing.

```
new_table = tbl(tbl(:,15)<0.95,:);
```

where tbl is your table of data.

```
tbl(:,15)<0.95
```

This gets the index where column 15 is less than 0.95, which is then used to extract the relevant rows.

Comment: Please pay attention while [reviewing edits](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5196219)